# Корректировка столбцов в pivot tables pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Коллеги, помогите подкорректировать столбцы в датафрейме:

Исходный датафрейм:

```
Регистрационный номер  Год  Наименование      Значение
1034700581190         2014 Основные средства 244710.0
1034700581190         2014 Активы            234987645.0
1034700581190         2014 Запасы            3487569
```

Я создал pivot table чтобы видоизменить табличное представление

```
spark_fin_rows.pivot_table(index=['Регистрационный номер', 'Год'], columns=['Наименование'], values=['Значение'], fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Я получил следующий датафрейм

```
Регистрационный номер  Год    Значение
                               Основные средства Активы      Запасы   
    1034700581190      2014    244710.0          234987645.0   3487569
```

Как сделать так, чтобы убрать название столбца "Значение", а Основные средства Активы, Запасы остались.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [88]: pvt
Out[88]:
             Регистрационный номер   Год   Значение
Наименование                                 Активы   Запасы Основные средства
0                    1034700581190  2014  234987645  3487569            244710

In [89]: res = pvt.rename(columns={"Значение":""})

In [90]: res.columns = [t[0] if t[0] else t[1] for t in res.columns]

In [91]: res
Out[91]:
   Регистрационный номер   Год     Активы   Запасы  Основные средства
0          1034700581190  2014  234987645  3487569             244710
```

---

**UPDATE:**  использовал ваш `raw_data.xls`:

```
In [130]: df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\download\raw_data.xls", index_col=0)

In [131]: pvt = df.pivot_table(index=['Регистрационный номер', 'Год'], columns=['Наименование'], values=['Значение'], fill_value=0).reset_index()

In [132]: res = pvt.rename(columns={"Значение":""})

In [133]: res.columns = [t[0] if t[0] else t[1] for t in res.columns]

In [134]: res
Out[134]:
    Регистрационный номер   Год  Активы  всего  Валовая прибыль (убыток)  Внеоборотные активы  ...  \
0           1027807593549  2014          16666                         0                16372  ...
1           1027807593549  2015          20908                         0                20498  ...
2           1027807593549  2016          24526                         0                23637  ...
3           1027807593549  2017          71643                         0                68818  ...
4           1034700581190  2014         294590                     74698               251908  ...
5           1034700581190  2015         284245                    100225               233813  ...
6           1034700581190  2016         223843                    110387               222945  ...
..                    ...   ...            ...                       ...                  ...  ...
```

Comment: выдает ошибку IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @Pavel, можете привести пример данных, который позволит воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/KSak1_4J_mls-A

Comment: @Pavel, у меня все работает - смотрите UPDATE...

Comment: все заработало) Спасибо большое! pivot_table было без объявления переменной и из-за этого выдавало ошибку в дальнейшем :) СПАСИБО!